# CGAL 3D Skin Surface Meshing with many Points

Tags: cgal

I am trying to skin a large amount of particles with CGAL, basically following the [example in the docs](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Skin_surface_3/index.html#Chapter_3D_Skin_Surface_Meshing).
This easily needs more than 15 GB of RAM with 16k particles.

Why does it need so much memory and how can I reduce the memory usage?
I cannot reduce the amount of particles.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, internally a marching tetrahedra is used to produce the mesh. I guess the whole structure is meshed at once and requires a lot of memory. This packages has not been touched for a long time now. I guess we could improve it by replacing the internal mesher by the generic CGAL mesher but this would require some work.